# Issue with mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
  `c`.`id` AS `confession_id`,
  `c`.`account_id` AS `confession_author_id`,
  `c`.`confession_text`,
  `c`.`anonymous`,
  `c`.`total_likes`,
  `c`.`total_comments`,
  `c`.`creation_date`,
  `a`.`username`,
  `col`.`name` AS `college`,
  `col`.`avatar_url`,
  `cll`.`deleted` AS `tacc_exists` 
FROM
  `confessions` AS `c` 
  LEFT JOIN `accounts` AS `a` 
    ON `a`.`id` = `c`.`account_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `colleges` AS `col` 
    ON `col`.`id` = `c`.`college_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `confession_likes_log` AS `cll` 
    ON `cll`.`confession_id` = `c`.`id` 
    AND `cll`.`account_id` = :taccd_user 
    AND `c`.`college_id` IN ('9') 
ORDER BY `c`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

It's suppose to select entries from specified colleges based on the college id(s) supplied

```
AND `c`.`college_id` in ('9')
```

Although for some reason it is selecting entries even when the college_id is not the one specified. I was having troubles figuring out how to do the and clause with the left joins so I may have not formatted the query correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `where` clause:

```
              FROM `confessions` AS `c` LEFT JOIN
                   `colleges` AS `col`
                    ON `col`.`id` = `c`.`college_id` LEFT JOIN
                   `confession_likes_log` AS `cll`
                    ON `cll`.`confession_id` = `c`.`id` AND
                       `cll`.`account_id` = :taccd_user AND
                        `c`.`college_id` in ('9')
```

The way a `left join` works is:  Run the test in the `on` clause.  If there is no match for a given row in the first table, then include the row with `NULL` values from the right table.  Guess what.  This even applies to conditions on the *first* table.

So, the filter `c.college_id in ('9') isn't doing what you think.  You need to move it to a`where` clause:

```
              FROM `confessions` AS `c` LEFT JOIN
                   `colleges` AS `col`
                    ON `col`.`id` = `c`.`college_id` LEFT JOIN
                   `confession_likes_log` AS `cll`
                    ON `cll`.`confession_id` = `c`.`id` AND
                       `cll`.`account_id` = :taccd_user
              WHERE `c`.`college_id` in ('9')
```